# Pagination wont work with search results template

Tags: wp-query, pagination, search

I can't seem to get pagination to work correctly in my search results template. The page links appear, but when i click onto page 2, it gives me a 404 error.

**Search.php**

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$total_results = $wp_query->found_posts;
?>

<?php
if(!$wp_query) global $wp_query;
$search_refer = $_GET["post_type"];
if ($search_refer == 'archive') { load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/search-gallery.php');}
else{load_template(TEMPLATEPATH . '/search-standard.php');}
?>
```

**Pagination Code in Functions.php**

```
function pagination($pages = '', $range = 4){  
 $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

 global $paged;
 if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

 if($pages == '')
 {
     global $wp_query;
     $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
     if(!$pages)
     {
         $pages = 1;
     }
 }   

 if(1 != $pages)
 {
     echo "<div class=\"pagination\"><span>Page ".$paged." of ".$pages."</span>";
     if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo; First</a>";
     if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo; Previous</a>";

     for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
     {
         if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
         {
             echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class=\"current\">".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class=\"inactive\">".$i."</a>";
         }
     }

     if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href=\"".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."\">Next &rsaquo;</a>";  
     if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>Last &raquo;</a>";
     echo "</div>\n";
 }
}
```

**Search Results Template**

```
    <?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $search_query = array(
        'posts_per_page' => '10',
        'paged' => $paged,
        );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($search_query);

    if ($wp_query->have_posts()) : while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>


<div class="courseContent coursesLayout alumniMainContent alumniSpacing newsBoxMore">
        <div class="courseContentHolder alumniContentHolder newsBoxMainHolder">
            <div class="newsMainImage">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="alumniHeading newsMainHeading">
                <h5><?php the_title();?></h5>
            </div>

            <div class="alumniContent newsMainContent">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <span class="readmoreButton" style="display: inline !important;"><a title="Student Awards" href="<?php the_permalink();?>">Read More</a></span>
</div><?php edit_post_link('Edit'); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?><?php else : ?>       
    <p class="notfoundtext">Sorry, nothing came back matching what you searched. Try again?</p>
<?php endif; ?>     

<?php pagination(); ?>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is marked as a duplicate but there's no link to another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Page 1 on repeat is usually a wp_query issue. A 404 is a permalink issue - try setting them to default and see if the same problem occurs. If it doesn't, then switch them back to custom and your problem should have resolved itself.

If default permalinks give you a 404 on page two then we need to look at that pagination code a bit more closely. Personally, I'm a fan of Justin Tadlock's code because it's flawless.

https://github.com/justintadlock/hybrid-core/blob/master/extensions/loop-pagination.php

Comment: I changed the permalink structure back to standard and it did the same thing, 404 issue, then i tried Justin Tadlock's code but it exhibits strange behaviour, it has page 1 on repeat and page 1 on the links section is highlighted no matter what page I am on!

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting `$wp_query` inside the search template. That means that the main query that runs *before* your search template loads is going to be out or sync with the `$wp_query` in the template. That tends to cause 404s.

Since the only thing you are doing is changing the `posts_per_page` a very simple `pre_get_posts` callback will fix at least part of this.

```
function alter_search_ppp_wpse_106961($qry) {
  if ($qry->is_main_query() && $qry->is_search()) {
    $qry->set('post_per_page',10);
  }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts','alter_search_ppp_wpse_106961');
```

With that is place you do not need, and *should remove*, this:

```
$search_query = array(
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
    'paged' => $paged,
    );
$wp_query = new WP_Query($search_query);
```

I don't know why you've rolled your own pagination, and I can't tell by looking at it if that code is going to generate problem `URL`s, but I'd suggest you look into [`paginate_links`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links)

Comment: Thank you, I thought it might had been overwriting the $wp_query. I tried the pre_get_posts but it didn't do anything

Comment: "it didn't do anything" is not very descriptive.

Comment: The code that you gave caused no change in regards to making the pagination worked. When i performed a search, it did not limit it to 10 posts per page, it showed all. I tried removing my custom pagination and adding paginate_links and it did nothing. Is that better?

Comment: What is the name of your search template `.php` file?

Comment: I have search.php which contains the code in my original question, which directs to two other templates and the one i want the pagination to work on is named search-standard.php

Comment: Try again. There was a typo. If that still doesn't work then probably the `is_search` condition is not being met because of the way you are juggling templates.

Comment: Thanks, tried and tested but to no success! I may forget the notion, but thank you very much for you help, very much appreciated!