# WP_Query Pagination on multiple-loop page breaks WP or doesn't show up

Tags: wp-query, pagination

The loop below is one of several on a Custom Page template, but it's the only loop that I'm trying to implement Pagination with.

Once I have Pagination working for this one loop, I'll be implementing InfiniteScroll which I'm sure will be way easier than installing it first...

I've read miles of pages but my brain just isn't finding the right information to get this to work yet.

Designing themes is one thing, but engineering loops is still something I struggle with.

```
    <div class="thirdLeft">
            <?php
            global $paged;
            $curpage = $paged ? $paged : 1;
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'location',
                'orderby' => 'post_date',
                'posts_per_page' => 5,
                'paged' => $paged
            );
            $first_query = new WP_Query('cat=2,-20&showposts=18&offset=2');
            while($first_query->have_posts()) : $first_query->the_post();
            ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>  
            <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
```

**UPDATE**

After scouring the web, I found this great tut:
http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2008/04/19/paging-and-custom-wordpress-loops/

Formatting my loop above to work and get the pagination it deserves, an updated version looks like this:

(not much changed from the tut, aside from custom categories)

```
    <?php add_filter('post_limits', 'my_post_limit'); ?>
    <div class="thirdLeft">
            <?php
                global $myOffset;
                $myOffset = 2;
                $temp = $wp_query;
                $wp_query= null;
                $wp_query = new WP_Query();
                $wp_query->query('offset='.$myOffset.'&cat=2,-20'.'&showposts=18'.'&paged='.$paged);
            ?>
            <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
    </div>
        <div class="longLoopNav">
          <div class="alignleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous') ?></div>
          <div class="alignright"><?php next_posts_link('More &raquo;') ?></div>
        </div>
        <?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;?>
        <?php remove_filter('post_limits', 'my_post_limit'); ?>
```

Now to figure out Infinite Scroll to load more posts into this loop with Ajax

Comment: Please look at the related posts on the right. The standard pagination functions are not meant to work with, and do not work well with secondary queries.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I've read handfuls of them and most are trying to implement this and getting results but not much mention of multiple loops from what I've seen so far. I'll keep looking. Can you recommend any methods to help the progress of the question?

Comment: Related: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/77666/21376

Comment: Related: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/106997/21376

Comment: Related: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/104488/21376

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix pagination for custom loops?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops)

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you write custom pagination?

```
function theme_get_next_posts_link($query, $label = null, $max_page = 0)    
    {       
        global $paged;      
        if(!$max_page) $max_page = $query->max_num_pages;       
        if(!$paged) $paged = 1;     
        $nextpage = intval($paged) + 1;     
        if(null === $label) $label = "Older Posts";     
        if(!is_single() && $nextpage <= $max_page):         
            $attr = apply_filters( 'next_posts_link_attributes', '' );          
            echo '<a class="page-l" href="' . next_posts( $max_page, false ) . "\" $attr>" . preg_replace('/&([^#])(?![a-z]{1,8};)/i', '&$1', $label) . '</a>';     
        endif;  
    }       

    function theme_get_previous_posts_link($label = null)   
    {       
        global $paged;      
        if(null === $label) $label = "Newer Posts";     
        if(!is_single() && $paged > 1):         
            $attr = apply_filters( 'previous_posts_link_attributes', '' );          
            echo '<a class="page-r" href="' . previous_posts( false ) . "\" $attr>". preg_replace( '/&([^#])(?![a-z]{1,8};)/', '&$1', $label ) .'</a>';     
        endif;  
    }
```

Using:
`<?php theme_get_next_posts_link($first_query); ?>` for Older Posts
`<?php theme_get_previous_posts_link(); ?>` for Newer Posts

In your code:

```
<?php
    global $paged;
    $args = array(
        'post_type'=>'post',
        'post_status'=> 'publish',
        'paged'=> $paged,
        'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1,
        'posts_per_page'=>10 // -1 - all
    );
    $fp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $fp_query->have_posts() ):
    while ($fp_query->have_posts()) : $fp_query->the_post();
?>
    Posts
<?php endwhile;?>
    <div class="longLoopNav">
        <div class="alignleft"><?php theme_get_next_posts_link($fp_query); ?></div>
        <div class="alignright"><?php theme_get_previous_posts_link(); ?></div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I'm still relatively new to working with custom queries, but this looks really thorough. Would you be able to guide me a little with a run through of what you're doing here?

Comment: I added example of using in my post.